# How to generate a string consisting of 16 digits but between every 4 numbers there is a hyphen(-)?

Tags: python

What kind of technique would allow me to generate a string in Python similar to this output:

```
1234-1234-1234-1234
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a built in `wrap` function, made to split strings like this. In conjunction with `string.join`, you can rejoin the split string with your character of choice:

```py
from textwrap import wrap

s = '1234567890abcdef'
print('-'.join(wrap(s, 4)))
>>> 1234-5678-90ab-cdef
```

The wrap function takes your string, and the number of characters to split on (in this case 4).
The result from this is used in `'-'.join` to join each element together with dashes, which gives the result you were looking for.

Note: if you're starting with a number instead of a string, you can easily convert it using `str()`:

```py
s = str(1234567890123456)
print('-'.join(wrap(s, 4)))
>>> 1234-5678-9012-3456
```

Comment: Digits are 1,2,3,4,5......

Comment: This code works for any string - I just used 1-f because it's a good sample of 16 unique characters.